# Multiple React render Components: How to share state?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm using React and Typescript to create and manage multiple small components on the same static page which works really well so far. I have a few contexts wrapped in a state provider component like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <StateProvider>
    <Reps />
  </StateProvider>,
  document.getElementById("react-reps")
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <StateProvider>
    <Script />
  </StateProvider>,
  document.getElementById("react-script")
);
```

Even though `StateProvider` is used in both render methods, each one is a separate instance and has independent state.

I'd like to share some of the state between these components, though as I understand it I may have to manually push updates around rather than relying on React (since the updates will transcend the calls to ReactDom.render) but I still can't figure out if there is a canonical way to achieve this. I've been pushing some state around via events which works well for actions the user takes, but is less great for taking action onload because I don't want to rely on timing for which component loads first.

What's the best way to automatically or manually share *some* state between these two or more components?

**Edit:** the comment below for how sharing the store from redux is the kind of thing I want to achieve but I would much rather use the contexts I have right now than introduce redux as a dependency. How could this work with contexts?

Comment: What's the reason to not use React for the entire page and share context?

Comment: @TrueWill most of the content on the page is static html and doesn't need to use react, it's already rendered. It's not an SPA either so keeping the components small and loading them on every page has worked well.

Comment: Thanks - note that React is going to render static HTML _really_ fast. You could also consider https://www.gatsbyjs.com/ - static HTML + React.

Answer (score 0):

Try, Redux and React-redux for state management and transferring data between different components. It is handy and professional. It works a bit differently, but once you get then it is very easy to manage.

Comment: I've used Redux but as far as I know it will only work inside a single ReactDOM.render and not between them. If you can provide an example otherwise I'd love to know more.

Comment: if your store is same then you can use them like this

Comment: ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><Header /></Provider>, document.getElementById('header'));
ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><Footer /></Provider>, document.getElementById('footer'));

Comment: Ideally we could do this in the same way with the existing contexts / state provider by sharing a store object and not require another dependency. Do you have an idea for how that might work?

Comment: `Do you have an idea for how that might work?` You need to create a global object in which to store one or more values, and it needs to be an event emitter so other pieces of code can be notified when the value(s) change. Then you need to have components in each of your component trees register for those events, and when the events are fired the components set react state.

Comment: @NicholasTower thanks, that sounds like a good plan. If you made this suggestion an answer I will mark it as the right one.